# Standard Output Method

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder

I know you can use a text field to display output but there is a limit on the size of the box.  I can I display a message to the screen, without using text field?  I'm not really finding anything useful so far in a couple books.

Comment: Why is the size limit of a UITextfield's frame a problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using,

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 0.0f, round(fontSize / 4.0f));
CGContextShowText(context, [text UTF8String], strlen([text UTF8String]));
```